# Get values of matrix

Tags: arrays, matrix

I made many calculations with matrices and as a result I get the 2x1 matrix.
If i use the matrix.print class it prints the values.
However I want to save the values in two variables but if I use the class matrix.get(int m, int n),
it gives an ArrayOutOfBoundException.
I hope someone has an answer to my problem.

Comment: Hi, there are many different programming languages used on Stack Overflow. Could you please tag your question with the one you are using. Also, no one is going to be able to tell why your're getting an exception without the code that generates it. Can you please [edit] your question with a **minimal** example that reproduces this problem.

Comment: My guess is the order of your indices is wrong

Comment: Be sure you know where the index range of your matrix starts (maybe 0, maybe 1). In general, not enough context provided. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without actually seeing code, but are you sure you have your matrix dimensions right? I.e. could it be 1x2 instead of 2x1? Try switching your arguments to the `get` method and see what happens. Another thing to check: Does your matrix package use 1-indexing or 0-indexing? I.e. is the first row/column numbered 0 or 1?